# Changing the max query string length in express

Tags: node.js, http, express, get, uri

Does anyone know what the max query string length in `express` is and how to set it to be a larger amount?

It seems that for running local requests, I get a `StatusCodeError: 414` when doing a GET request with more than 4096 characters in the URI.